# How to remove data before update

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have newer version app to update to app store, but since there were some obsolete data: such as database and some files that I don't need in the newer build or some databases which are use same name as newer build but the DB structure is different, so is there a way to remove all personal data of last version when user do the update? Then after user updated my app the app feels like a brand-new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On app start up you can simply remove the entire store file with something like this.

```
NSString *path = <path to your file> 
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[self persistentStorePath] error:nil];
```

You can use this code to get the path to the documents directory, if that is where you store the data.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *path = [[[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"subdirectoryIfAny"] 
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name of your .sql or whatever"];
```

If you do not want to blow away all the data, then you have read in the records you want to delete and then manually remove them.

Comment: oh dear, that's unbelievable fast!!! Tks, mate! But how can I control the delete action only do once for the first time app run up?

Comment: set a NSUserDefaults key, like alreadyDeletedOldData, then check it. If NOT set then do the delete and set the flag. If it IS SET then don't do the delete.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the entire contents of your application's sandbox *in one fell swoop* is really something that only can be accomplished by the user removing and re-installing your application.

There are two things to consider here:

1. If you know where the database/files reside, you can use the `NSFileManager` methods to remove them explicitly. Especially `removeItemAtPath:error:`. The [Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is quite helpful.
2. You should proceed with caution when clearing out the entire application's state. **Do your users know this is going to happen? Are they going to lose sensitive data?**

Comment: oh dear, that's unbelievable fast!!! Tks, mate!But how can I control the delete action only do once for the first time app run up?

Answer (score 2):

There is a pattern that you can follow.

Let's say you db is called MySqliteDatabase.sqlite. There is some other data in Documents directory but you dont want to use it and delete it on first install of next version.

With the new version, rename the db to MySqliteDatabasev2.sqlite. On appstartup, use NSFileManager to look for MySqliteDatabasev2.sqlite in the documents directory. If it doesn't exist, blow away the documents directory and copy My SqliteDatabasev2.sqlite there.

For any subsequent launches, the above logic will find the v2 data and will do nothing with the documents directory.

For any subsequent version upgrades, you can follow this scheme to update database name.

**Have caution:** make sure to change rest of the code to use the new name as well. Best practice for that is to define it in some commons header file (i have a commons.h in every project)

```
#define DB_NAME @"MySqliteDbv2.sqlite"
```

and then make sure everywhere you are just using DB_NAME and nothing anything else. So whenever version changes:
1. rename the db file in xcode navigator.
2. rename the DB_NAME define.

That's it.